# Using Multiple functions with ddply in R

Tags: r

I was wondering how to apply multiple functions with ddply. Let's say you have a dataframe where you want to calculate the mean, sd and total count on a groups within the data and you want to add these columns (with labels).

Any ideas or examples available?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `?ddply`, pay  attention to the examples where you find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 6):

You can apply multiple functions and use `,` to separate them:

```
dat <- data.frame(group = gl(2, 2), value = 1:4)
#   group value
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     2
# 3     2     3
# 4     2     4

library(plyr)

ddply(dat, .(group), summarize, 
      M = mean(value), SD = sd(value), total = sum(value))
#   group   M        SD total
# 1     1 1.5 0.7071068     3
# 2     2 3.5 0.7071068     7
```

Comment: alternatively, `ddply(dat, .(group), with, each(sd, mean, sum)(value))`

Comment: Thanks for both approaches. Perfect!